# Does this mean my university is storing passwords insecurely?

Tags: security, encryption, passwords

My university requires you to change passwords regularly. If I try any variation on my current password I get the message:

> The new password you have entered is
>   not acceptable for the following
>   reason: That password is too similar
>   to the old one! Please try again
>   please go back and try again.

Now I'm no cryptographer, but if they can compute a similarity measure between the new and old passwords, doesn't this mean that passwords are being stored insecurely, or even in plaintext?

EDIT: I may be being an idiot. They do require you to enter the current password as well.

Comment: I think so. They either encrypted it with a known key or stored is as plaintext. But they might store it only in the session, or if you entered it when changing the password they don't need to store it at all.

Comment: "doesn't this mean that passwords are being stored insecurely, or even in plaintext?" ...or a third option, that they are being stored securely

Comment: Seems puzzling, does it not, Mr. E. Nygma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have to enter your current password when changing passwords?  Perhaps they're verifying that the current password hashes to the right value, and the comparing the plaintext to the new password.

Comment: In addition, some implementations store _old_ passwords in the clear to do just such a comparison throughout a history of passwords.  Keep this in mind when selecting passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite. They could take the new password you entered, change a character and check the hash of the altered password against the stored hash. Repeat this for a series of minor alterations, e.g. modifying/inserting/deleting a single character and if any of the hashes generated equal the one stored then give the error you see.

Example: Say your old password is "password" and you try change to "pssword". Insert "a" after the "p" gives you "password", which hashes to the same thing as the old password. Therefore without knowing the old password, but only the hash, we have determined that the passwords are similar.

For a password of length N, this generates and compares O(3N) = O(N) hashes. Assuming a hash takes O(N) to compute, the overall complexity will be O(N^2) which is very feasible for passwords all the way up to 1,000 characters.

There is a very rare chance of a hash collision, and the more alterations they consider similar the higher this chance. But it's still rare nonetheless.

Note that this doesn't guarantee that the passwords are being stored securely. It just means you c an't conclude that they are **not** being stored securely.

Comment: This would be a bad hash algorithm. Similar plaintexts should produce wildly different hashes.

Comment: If this is the case, then the hash function would be insecure. A good cryptographic hash should have strong avalanching properties, so that changing even a tiny amount of the original data will completely change the hash.

Comment: @skaffman Correct on the latter, but this is generating hashes from the altered passwords.

Comment: I think he's talking about "change/remove/add a character, compare hashes, repeat N times or until hashes are the same". That could be quite time-consuming though, depending on the definition of "similar".

Comment: @Justin Spahr-Summers No, read carefully. Say your old password is "password" and try change to "pssword". Insert "a" after the "p" giving you "password", hash that and you get the same hash as "password".

Comment: @marcog My bad, I missed that sentence. I think that's highly unlikely, however, given the computational complexity of such a check.

Comment: @Justin Spahr-Summers Not true. If your password is of length N, then this requires O(N^2) computation since you're generating O(3N) hashes.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux (and other Unix-like systems) there are two PAM authentication modules that are responsible for this:

(1) Using the remember= option for the [pam_unix](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_unix) PAM authentication module. This stores a number of past passwords in their hashed form so that you cannot reuse an old password with no changes. A usual location for those old hashes is /etc/security/opasswd.

(2) The [pam_cracklib](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_cracklib) PAM module uses the old password as you entered it in order to perform the change and checks if enough characters are different when compared to the new password you entered (see the difok= pam_cracklib option).

In no case are old passwords stored in a recoverable form...

Any semi-competent system administrator would use something similar, rather than reinvent the wheel, which probably (but not certainly) means that you should not worry.

Answer (score 0):

> doesn't this mean that passwords are being stored insecurely, or even in plaintext?

Could be. A pure hashing-based storage method would make it impossible to compare for similarity: Only perfectly identical passwords could be found out that way.

They *could* be using an algorithm like [SOUNDEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) to check similarity - that wouldn't be as awful a practice as storing plaintext passwords, but still a terrible thing to do.

But of course, it's possible that the passwords are stored as plain text. You'd have to ask.